# Create a menu that expands on click

Tags: routes

I want to create a menu that expands on click . ( For example, facebook, gmail, twitter all have menus at the top right where onl click the we get account settings , log out etc.)

What is the best way to do this in drupal? Is there any module for this or do I need to do it in theme?

Also, is there any special name for such menus?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which drupal 6/7 ? 
See here http://www.pixelclever.com/custom-drupal-themes-drupal-5-and-drupal-6 
and this [JQuery menu](http://drupal.org/project/jquerymenu) module.

Jquery menu uses simple, cross browser compatible jquery to transform your multilevel menus into click and expand menus. Yes this module is similar to dhtml menus and active menus, but it is different in a couple of key ways.

1. Unlike dhtml menus (which requires you to click twice on a link to actually follow an expanded link) Jquery menus separates the link from the expanding mechanism (there is a small plus symbol that you click instead to expand the menu). This makes for a more natural navigation.
2. Unlike active menus, which makes ajax calls to fill in the lower level menus when you click the plus symbol, Jquery menu creates the menu in full on the initial page load. I personally have used active menus for several months and have found that those ajax calls sometimes fail, and are not as stable as jquery.
3. Unlike Active menus which transforms all menus into active menus once the module is turned on, Jquery menu only creates a jquery block for the menus that you specify. To chose which menus you want to be active you just have to visit the admin page at 'admin/settings/jquerymenu' .
4. Jquery menu is easily themable. Since the jquery menu blocks only use a small number of styles, and don’t use the default list styles, overriding it with your own css is easy. Also the important display elements are contained in themable functions so you can tinker with the layout if you like.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I originally suggested [Nice Menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) (60,000+ installs) and [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) (30,000+ installs).  However, Nice Menus [does not have onclick behavior](http://drupal.org/node/352711).  There is an [onclick Superfish library](https://gist.github.com/917446) but I don't know how difficult this would be to integrate into Drupal.

An alternative that can do onclick would be [Dynamic Persistent Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dynamic_persistent_menu).

Comment: As far I as I think, these are on-hover not on-click, isn't it?

Comment: Updated and fixed my answer.

Comment: Dynamic Persistent Menu works perfectly for me. It not only allows click-to-open, but it also pushes the other page content down when the menu is expanded, instead of displaying the drop-down menu links as an overlay. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you need light and customized menu I suggest you write your own, follow this steps:

1. create your menu via admin interface
2. mark as expanded your parents items in menu
3. some css to hide child
4. some javascript to reveal childs on parent click or hover

if you have menu with `#menu` as ID then css example:

```
css rule for parents
css rule for childs (level 2)
css rule for childs (deeper levels)
css rule for initiate menu like:
ul#menu ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: ??px;
  width: ??px;
  z-index: 100;
```

}

and some javascript like:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('ul#menu>li').hoverIntent(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('>ul').fadeIn('fast');
  },function(){
    jQuery(this).find('>ul').fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have contributed a module which integrates with Drupal Nice Menus and provide "on-click" support for nice menus.

https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus_onclick

You can try it in your project without changing your theme files or write any CSS.